# Unexpected token on valid typescript file

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, jestjs, nrwl-nx

When starting jest with a pattern from intelliJ (`jest --testNamePattern=MySpecialComponent`), i get an error on my `jest.config.ts` stating

```
Error: Jest: Failed to parse the TypeScript config file /home/asc/www/dmg/admin-center-frontend/jest.config.ts
  SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='
    at readConfigFileAndSetRootDir (/www/node_modules/jest-config/build/readConfigFileAndSetRootDir.js:116:13)
    at async readInitialOptions (/www/node_modules/jest-config/build/index.js:403:13)
    at async readConfig (/www/node_modules/jest-config/build/index.js:147:48)
    at async readConfigs (/www/node_modules/jest-config/build/index.js:424:26)
    at async runCLI (/www/node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:151:59)
    at async Object.run (/www/node_modules/jest-cli/build/run.js:130:37)
```

The jest.config.ts looks like this:

```
import { getJestProjects } from '@nx/jest';

export default {
  projects: getJestProjects(),
};
```

I can't see any error in the `jest.config.ts` and do not understand the problem.

If i run all tests, without pattern, it does not show this error.

Comment: What version of node are you using?

Comment: @derpirscher It was indeed a node version issue. IntelliJ IDEA was using an older Version of node (14) and it had to be 18.

Answer (score 2):

It was indeed a node version issue. IntelliJ IDEA was using an older Version of node (14) and it had to be 18.

You can set the Node Version directy in the Test Result Window with the little Wrench Icon.